# comparing string vectors to get the difference

Tags: c++, vector

trying to store the different elements of 2 vectors into another vectore.

here is what I have so far but its not giving me the right output!

```
for (long i=0; i<(long)v2.size(); ++i)
                {
                        for (long index=0; index<(long)v1.size(); ++index)
                        {
                            if (v2[i] == v1[index])
                            {
                                v3.push_back(v2[i]);
                            }
                        }
                }
```

so v1 has { S A B D} and v2 has { S a b h A j k k B D r y u i o} Im trying to get all the following { a b h j k k r y u i o} into v3

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you are expecting this algorithm to do and if any assumptions can be made about v1 and v2. Try giving an example.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that you're storing all the equal elements of the two vectors instead of the different ones. From what you describe, this should work:

```
for (long i=0; i<(long)v2.size(); ++i)
{
  for (long index=0; index<(long)v1.size(); ++index)
  {
    if (v2[i] != v1[index])
    {
      // Need to store both since they're different...
      // this is weird but it's what you asked for :/
      v3.push_back(v2[i]);
      v3.push_back(v1[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

But if not, please provide details of the input you're using and why the output is not what you expect.

Comment: So I tried that I get segmentation fault! so v1 has { S A B D} and v2 has { S a b h A j k k B D r y u i o} Im trying to get all the following { a b h j k k r y u i o} into v3